# iAds constatly didFailToRecieveWithError

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, iad

I run these apps on the iOS simulator only: I created a iOS application that I have never released and has been working fine for the iPad and iPhone simulator for the past year. Two days ago the app was working fine. I didnt' change anything or even login to my Mac and tonight I go to test the app before adding additional features and the iAds stop appearing. I check over my code to verify nothing has changed. When I run the app I keep getting constant 'didFailToRecieveWithError' over and over in the log window. I know I used to get these intermittently in the past between test ads, but now that's all that I get. Has anyone else experienced this? Do the iAd test servers go down once in a while?

Comment: it's probably nothing to worry about

Comment: there's a iAd fill rate settings on the simulator? well, let me go check that.

Comment: Jerome Diaz: I'm creating another app and I need to verify that iAds are appearing correctly on the second application.

Comment: Where are the iAd fill rate settings?

Comment: I haven't seen an iAd in the simulator for a few days now.

Comment: Thanks Paul. That's what I wanted to confirm.

Comment: I'm trying to show iAds for 2 days with the same code always: "Ad inventory unavailable"

Comment: The issue seems to be at the server not my app then.